# Flutter - Which state management approach is good for apps with multiple data streams?

Tags: flutter, state-management

I would like to ask about state management methods for Flutter. My apps have quite a bit of data streams, from Firestore to be specific and I would like to receive real-time changes from those streams.

I'm currently considering learning either Provider or BLoC.

Thank you!

Comment: Learn both. They both go hand in hand together.

Answer (score 0):

In packages, FlutterBloc has a Provider as a dependency.

Consider learning how to use the Streams with simple stream data and StreamBuilders, then learn bloc pattern without provider / bloc libraries (it is recommended that you know how to use ChangeNotifier or InheritedWidgets to understand it better) and then using packages.